# Is it possible to catch exceptions in ruby thrown over an entire class

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, jruby

I have test classes that inherit a class that inherits `Test::Unit::TestCase`. I overwrote the assertions so that I get output to a junit style test report for use in bamboo and jenkins. This works fine.

Now I want to catch exceptions if they occur throughout the test classes from setup, through multiple testcases and onto teardown. Outside putting in begin/resucue/end blocks in all the methods is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is but you need to dig (and understand some of the) `Test::Unit` internals.
what you're trying to achieve is probably easiest done by patching/replacing the [Test::Unit::TestCase#run](https://github.com/test-unit/test-unit/blob/e428f3f/lib/test/unit/testcase.rb#L455-L500) method with your own. be aware that this might break between versions so be sure to make patching "smart".

Comment: exactly what I did and it works great. Its a corporate environment so changing version is tightly controlled which suits this issue perfectly